# iOS instance variables not initialised from within a block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, parse-platform

i am using parse.com as backend for my app.
i need to get information from my backend and init an instance with this information.
i use this code in order to do so:

```
    - (id) initWithTeamId:(NSString *)teamId
{
__block NSString *str;
__block FrFTeam *blockSelf = self;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"teams"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:teamId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    str = [object objectForKey:@"teamName"];
    (void)[blockSelf initWithName:str players:nil thumb:nil];
}];

return self;
}
```

when this code is done self.name is set to null,
what am i doing wrong?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// call init on the object, then setup the team id
- (id)initWithTeamId:(NSString *)teamId
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupWithTeamId:teamId];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setupWithTeamId:(NSString *)teamId
{
    __weak FrFTeam *blockSelf = self;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"teams"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:teamId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        NSString *name = [object objectForKey:@"teamName"];
        NSLog(@"Received name: %@ from object: %@", name, object);
        [blockSelf setName:name];
    }];
}
```

Then, change the name of the method from `initWithName:...` because this isn't really an init method because you have already done the init before calling  `setupWithTeamId:`.

If you need the parse bit to be done before the init method returns, you should:

1. Call parse to get the details before calling init on the object
2. Use `getObjectWithId:` --- not recommended as this blocks the thread in init, bad idea

Comment: thank you, this still don't work, after initing: FrFTeam *tmpTeam = [[FrFTeam alloc] init]; and using your method : [tmpTeam setupWithTeamId:team.objectId]; the name is still null

Comment: Immediately after calling that method it IS nil (and should be), as the completion handler at best is scheduled at the END of the current runloop, there is no way of having the name field be populated immediately without blocking for the request. My suggestion KVO, you can listen to the change in name (if set up properly) and act upon the change.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the reason is in the method name you are calling `-getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` (it specifies *InBackground*, which suggests the block is called at some later stage and not immediately)

This would suggest that you end up with self == nil (as you are not calling any other initialiser in the method.

Initialisation of an object has to be synchronous.

Comment: is there a way to get the data asynchronous, and init synchronous?

Comment: Only if you handle the init in a background thread, but the init itself has to be synchronous. I notice that you are passing quite a lot of nils to your initialiser, is the name string even necessary to initialise the object? Perhaps you could initialise it and THEN kick off the loading (asynchronously), which populates the name field? This is what the other answer does in the code given.

Comment: "This would suggest that you end up with self == nil" No. If you look at the OP's code, what is returned from the `initWithTeamId:` method is `self`, i.e. the object it is called on. Not `nil`.

Comment: OK, yes, you have that right, self will get returned. However, blockSelf is the one getting initialised in the block and the return value of that initialisation is never used, so I'd say that the end goal is still not achieved, in which case self might as well == nil (with the exception that the memory has been allocated for the object). I guess what I was trying to say is self != a fully initialised self, it's just a shell and not ready for use as per NSObjects documentation.